# Show modification (new and edited files) since a given date

Tags: date, tfs

How can I ask TFS to show me only modified files (new and edited files) in a workspace (or in a folder) since a given date.

Is it possible? or do I have to go myself through all the history and build my own "modification tree".

Answer (score 38):

Open the Source Control Explorer in Visual studio (View->Other Windows->Source Control Explorer), and select the top folder for your project.  Then right-click and view history.

This will show all check-ins for all code in this folder ordered by date.   Then select two dates from the list of check-ins, right click and choose "Compare".  For example if you wanted to see all of the code changed in the past month click the most recent checkin and the checkin from a month ago.

This will show all of the code changed since those two points in time.  You can also choose just the past date to compare against your current code.  This works in VS2015 which is what I'm using right now.   Good Luck.

Comment: you can do this for a folder or just an individual file.

Comment: This is an invaluable feature.

Comment: Microsoft should have made this more intuitive. Thank you for helping me discover this very helpful capability of TFS. +1

Answer (score 29):

Use the [command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx)

```
tf history -noprompt -server:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/TeamProjectName/path
          -version:D2006-12-01T01:01:01Z~D2006-12-13T20:00:00Z -recursive
          -format:detailed -login:DOMAIN\name,password"
```

change the dates in the version flag to what you need and it should get you what you want.

Comment: You can also use Cnnnn (changeset), Llabel, "W" (Workspace) or "T" (latest) at either end of the versions. E.g. to see all changes in TFS but not in the workspace: "/version:W~T".

Comment: You can remove the 'Z' from the -version to use local datetime
tf history -noprompt -server:http://tfsserver:8080 $/TeamProjectName/path -version:D2006-12-01T01:01:01~D2006-12-13T20:00:00 -recursive -format:detailed -login:DOMAIN\name,password"

Answer (score 4):

If you open the menu item File->Source Control->Find In Source Control->Changesets... (you must be in Source Control Explorer for this to be available).  This will  open the Find Changesets dialog.  You can then search for change sets by date on a given source folder.

The down side is that you then have to click the details button on each change set to see which files were changed (Double Clicking closes the dialog).

If you are searching for changes this may be the better way.  It will allow more interactive searching.  If you are trying to print out a report for others to read (or for Change Documentation) then the command line way shown by Alex is better.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Source Control Explorer in VS10 (View->TeamExplorer->Source Control Explorer) and right click to project and click Compare. You can see different options for view. I normally use "Show items that are different" in order to see difference between local and server.